# Find method search text with special character in variable

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to create a macro that finds all text formulas and replaces it with OMath formulas.
I create a text, where all formulas are surrounded with special tags (in my case its word "formula"). Then I find all cases with regex and create variable that contains found formula. Then I give this variable to find method to create range, which I then modify.
Some formulas contain special characters (in my case its caret (^), which is used to create power) and find method doesn't select them.
How can I ignore special characters in variable that I give to find method?

Macro that I created:

```
Dim regexObject As Object
Set regexObject = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
Dim matches As Object
Dim objEq As OMath
Dim objRange As Range
Dim match As Object


regexObject.Pattern = "formula(.*?)formula"
regexObject.MultiLine = True

Selection.WholeStory
While regexObject.test(Selection.Text)
    Set matches = regexObject.Execute(Selection.Text)
    For Each match In matches
    MsgBox match
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = match
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .Execute
            Set objRange = Selection.Range
            objRange.Text = Mid(match, 8, Len(match) - 14)
            Set objRange = Selection.OMaths.Add(objRange)
            Set objEq = objRange.OMaths(1)
            objEq.BuildUp
        End With
        Selection.WholeStory
    Next
Wend
```

Sample Text:

```
formulaΨ=1,67∙0,72∙0,9∙1=1,09.formula
formulac_c=0,9formula
formulaE_q=Ψ WV_n^2/2,formula
formulac_m, c_e, c_c, c_sformula
```

Comment: You will do better by ditching RegEx and using wildcards in the Word Find function to find the tags. If you don’t know how to do this see https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm#:~:text=To%20begin%2C%20you%20must%20first%20turn%20Wildcards%20on,wildcard%20characters%20as%20if%20they%20were%20ordinary%20text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
Sub FindFormulaeCreateOMath()
    Dim objEq As OMath
    Dim findRange As Range
    Dim eqRange As Range
    
    Set findRange = ActiveDocument.Content
    With findRange
        With .Find
            .Text = "formula*formula"
            .MatchWildcards = True
        End With
        Do While .Find.Execute
            .Text = Mid(.Text, 8, Len(.Text) - 14)
            Set eqRange = findRange.OMaths.Add(.Duplicate)
            Set objEq = eqRange.OMaths(1)
            objEq.BuildUp
            .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```